# What does this notation mean? $∂df^2 / ∂x$

Tags: derivatives, notation, partial-derivative, error-propagation

I am given variance $\sigma_x$ and function $y=f(x)$

According to my book, the following equation gives the new variance of $y=f(x)$. But I'm not sure what this notation means, as in what this combination of $\partial$'s and $d$'s represents.

$$\Large{\sigma_y^2=\frac{\partial df^2}{\partial x} \sigma_x^2}$$

I understand that $\frac{\partial g}{\partial u}$ is the partial derivative of $g$ w.r.t $u$, but what does it mean when $g = df^2$ ?

Comment: It looks like that it is the partial derivative of the  square of $f(x)$. You take the square of $f(x)$ and differentiate it w.r.t. $x$.

Comment: Ok, then why wouldn't they just write $${\sigma_y^2=\frac{\partial f^2}{\partial x} \sigma_x^2}$$  ?

Comment: I suspect it's a typo, the extra "d"